# How to add multiple chat rooms in a WordPress website

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I am building a sports chat website and I cannot find a good method to add multiple chat rooms.

What I mean, for example - I want to create a chat room for each NFL team, but each chat room should be on its own page.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question.  Is there a certain plugin or script you are currently using to create chatrooms already?

Comment: No, that's just it... I cannot seem to find one that allows multiple individual rooms of different pages.

Comment: But how should we know what the problem is without implementation details?

Comment: Plugin recommendation questions are not allowed http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#questions  

Can you rephrase the question to be more specific?

Comment: Ya, I realize WPSE recently removed "recommendations" from the scope of "acceptable topics," which was the best part of WPSE... Lately, it seems a bit elitist towards coders and cares less to help out noobs and those who simply need a nudge in the right direction... Too bad the community has taken a step backwards...

Comment: Travis, if you haven't found a method to "add multiple", we can only infer that you've found a method to **add one**. Without disclosing at least this/one, your Question becomes a guessing game, not fit to this site format even under the old rules...

Comment: Travis, you're blaming the community for the sites scope, but it didn't even take you a hour to find what you were searching for... what for did you now exactly need WPSE? Saving you an hour of search (for a plugin that you then found in the official repo as first result for "chat room") ? Ok...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a plugin that seems to work - Chat Room - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/chat-room